# Deploy a webproject as a webservice

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am new to webservice. I exposed one class of myproject as a webservice. I also made a client to consume this. But one problem occur my class which I exposed as a webservice into the project which is a web project and the exposed class is communicate with hibernate for fetching the data but it fails because for fetching the necessary entities is not load. For loading the entities first we load a webservlet which is mentioned in the web.xml but my .aar is not contain the web.xml how can I include the web.xml in the .aar file or if any other way to deploy the project as a webservice. I am using the Axis2 and Tomcat6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of deploying web services in AXIS2:

**1) Hot deployment**

The one which you are doing, make .aar file of service classes and deploy it in axis2 web container in tomcat server. Any other necessary jars you have to add in the .aar. As for the web.xml, you have to necessary changes to the web-xml of axis2 container in tomcat6 web apps.

**2) Normal Deployment**

Second method is more easy and suitable in your case, create web-service using eclipse WTP tool and deploy your eclipse project as .war file. In this way you can have your project web-xml working. Check this link for help http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion I used Hot deployment and I got this error have u any idea about that Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)